# Copy column in spark dataframe to a new column in the same spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 5 columns that is already created.  One of the columns is packageid.  I need to duplicate that same column in the same dataframe.  This is what I need to see as output:

package id
field b
field c
field d
field e
package id 2

Can someone give me some help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

.withColumn("Package 2 Id",functions.col("packageId"))